# How to fix my Tic Tac Toe game’s code that only prints the top row of the board?

Tags: c

My Tic Tac Toe game is working fine internally. It isn’t exactly complete, but it can place X’s and O’s on the array. However, only the top row prints out. when printboardl1, 2 and 3 are invoked.

- Used  sleep function
- Split the function into three, here’s where we are now
- Searched for help, question is too specific

Code:

```
/* Put the functions themselves inside of a while loop in ascending order. Make a 2d array called tttarray, and add some X’s and O’s for examples. */ 
void printboardl1()
{
    printf( "%c", tttarray[1][1], "%c", tttarray[2][1], "%c", tttarray[3][1], "\n" );
}
void printboardl2()
{
    printf( "%c", tttarray[1][2], "%c", tttarray[2][2], "%c", tttarray[3][2], "\n" );
}
void printboardl3()
{
    printf( "%c", tttarray[1][3], "%c", tttarray[2][3], "%c", tttarray[3][3], "\n" );
}
```

I expected the board to fully print out, but only the first row prints out.

Comment: Read the docu on printf again please. Only use one format string.

Comment: Presuming `tttarray` is  declared as char `tttarray[3][3]` - which is exactly what I'd expected for tic-tac-toe, then you've got a bug in your print statements and undefined behavior in `printboardl3`.  Because `tttarray[2][3]` is not a valid index in a 3x3 array.  Do you see why?  Array indices for row and column should be between `0-2`/

Comment: printf("%c%c%c\n", tttarray[1][1], tttarray[1][2], tttarray[1][3])

Comment: As you can see below, answering helpfully and correctly is very hard without sufficient information. Please provide a [mcve]. It is for example very important to know the definition of `tttarray`. Your code only makes sense if you have defined the array as `tttarray[4][4]` and then intentionally avoid using the 0 indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming your board is declared as follows:

```
char tttarray[3][3];
```

Then to print out any single row, like the first row would be as follows:

```
printf("%c %c %c\n", tttarray[0][0], tttarray[0][1], tttarray[0][2]);
```

Printing out the second and third row:

```
printf("%c %c %c\n", tttarray[1][0], tttarray[1][1], tttarray[1][2]);
printf("%c %c %c\n", tttarray[2][0], tttarray[2][1], tttarray[2][2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 printf("%c %c %c\n", tttarray[1][3], tttarray[2][3], tttarray[3][3]);
```

That how you have to use printf, take a look at the man http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/printf.3.html

Comment: If you are printing `tttarrary[*][3]`, then what do you think is stored at indices 0, 1, **and** 2. ?

Comment: also `tttarray[3][*]);` is very suspicious

Comment: Maybe is it the border of the tiac tac toe game

Comment: @CharlesRA no, because of the OP remark "_only the top row prints out_", and if there is a border 5 char must be print